# Execute commands after sshpass login in the script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm an Ubuntu bash newbie. I successfully login to an sFTP server using `sshpass`. But once the connection is established I also need to download a directory from the server. My script cannot seem to pass the connection line though. This is what I have in my script (.sh) file:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p 'MY_PASSWORD' sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss MYUSER@MYSFTPSERVERADDRESS
echo "hello"
get -r Export
```

In the snipped above, my `echo` and my `get` are not executed. The terminal is waiting for my input with a `sftp>` prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better served using `scp` instead of `sftp` and sharing keys instead of putting the password in a script if you're able, but if you must use `sftp` for some reason, it can take its commands from a [heredoc](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) like:

```
sshpass -p 'MY_PASS' sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss MYUSER@MYSFTPSERVERADDRESS <<EOF
get -r Export
EOF
```

note that `echo` isn't a valid `sftp` command.

You can put whatever commands you want `sftp` to execute before the `EOF` and it will do them each in turn.

If all you want is to get that directory it's probably still simpler to use `scp` if you can:

```
sshpass -p 'MY_PASSWORD' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -r MYUSER@MYSFTPSERVERADDRESS:Export .
```

Comment: thanks for the correct answer. working now. yes, at first i went with sharing keys, but realized i don't have the right to create folders on the sftp server. so i am using this solution for now. not very secure, but working.